# Merge 2 tables into a query on unequal column

Tags: sql, h2

I have 2 Tables, both have a TIMESTAMP column

I would like to display all the rows of both tables merged together, sorted by this TIMESTAMP column.

It is very unlikely there are any rows in either table that have the exact same TIMESTAMP value.

How would I do this?

for simplicity, example:

- TABLEA - COLUMNS ID, TIMESTAMP, COLXYZ, COLZZZ
- TABLEB - COLUMNS ID, TIMESTAMP, COLABC, COLDEF, COLGHI

want:

RESULT - COLUMNS ID, TIMESTAMP, COLXYZ, COLZZZ, COLABC, COLDEF, COLGHI

sorted by TIMESTAMP ascending

If there's some wildcard way to do it without specifying the other columns, that would be better (I mean wildcard to grab all columns from the tables)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple union all should suffice. And just fill the missing columns on each table with null values.

```
SELECT ID, TIMESTAMP, COLXYZ, COLZZZ, NULL AS COLABC, NULL AS COLDEF, NULL AS COLGHI
FROM TABLEA
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, TIMESTAMP, NULL, NULL, COLABC, COLDEF, COLGHI
FROM TABLEB
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP;
```

I don't really see a way in which you could prevent having to spell out the column names of each table.

Comment: Are you sure that the orderby is applying for both tables?.

Comment: Yes, it wouldn't make sense to apply the ordering before doing the union.

Comment: thanks - will be a bit of typing, I have many more columns in the tables than in the example, but I'll do it as you suggested